# how to handle java null values

Tags: java, null

Im developing a small app and I wants to get the total when I click the button total . But if there are null values the code code dosen't work .So additionally following code was added .

```
int QtyOfChickenBurger;

if ((textField.getText().equals(null))) {
    QtyOfChickenBurger = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText())*0;
} else {
    QtyOfChickenBurger = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()) * 70;
}
```

But still my application don't output the total when the textField is empty. So please help me to fix this.This is the full code.

```
JButton bttotal = new JButton("Total");
bttotal.setBounds(21, 37, 145, 25);
bttotal.setFont(new Font("Thoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
bttotal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg) {

            int QtyOfChickenBurger;

            if ((textField.getText().equals(null))) {

                QtyOfChickenBurger = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText())*0;
            } else {
                QtyOfChickenBurger = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()) * 70;
            }

            int QtyOfChickenBurgerMeal = Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText()) * 120;
            int QtyOfCheeseBurger = Integer.parseInt(textField_3.getText()) * 340;
            int QtyOfDrinks = Integer.parseInt(enterQTY.getText());
            int spriteCost = Integer.parseInt(enterQTY.getText()) * 55;
            int cokaColaCost = Integer.parseInt(enterQTY.getText()) * 60;
            int pepsiCost = Integer.parseInt(enterQTY.getText()) * 40;
            int lemonJuceCost = Integer.parseInt(enterQTY.getText()) * 35;
            int sum = (QtyOfChickenBurger + QtyOfChickenBurgerMeal + QtyOfCheeseBurger);
            lblDisplayCostOfMeals.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
            String x = String.valueOf(comboBox.getSelectedItem());

            if (x == "Sprite") {

                lblDisplayCostOfDrinks.setText(Integer.toString(spriteCost));
            } else if (x == "Select the drink") {
                lblDisplayCostOfDrinks.setText("0");
            } else if (x == "Coka Cola") {
                lblDisplayCostOfDrinks.setText(Integer.toString(cokaColaCost));
            } else if (x == "Pepsi") {
                lblDisplayCostOfDrinks.setText(Integer.toString(pepsiCost));
            } else if (x == "Lemon juce") {
                lblDisplayCostOfDrinks.setText(Integer.toString(lemonJuceCost));
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `textField.getText().equals(null)` can never be true. Did you mean `textField.getText() == null`?

Comment: See also [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1553851)

Comment: this is as well a ticking bomb: ***if x == "Sprite"***

Comment: yes i mean that.so how can i fix that

Comment: get the string from the text field and if you can use commons library and just do StringUtils.isBlank() it covers both empty and null.

Comment: you need to remove the else part as well, can't convert empty into int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is wrong

```
if ((textField.getText().equals(null))) {    
    QtyOfChickenBurger = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText())*0;
}
```

if the `textField.getText()` is null then you can not parse the `null` into `Integer`. In addition, you multiply 0 with a number for what? => just set it to 0.
Change it to

```
if (textField.getText()==null || textField.getText().equals("")){
    QtyOfChickenBurger = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using Swing JTextField which is a JTextComponent.

getText is returning a String therefore, you will need to check if its null or empty, before parsing it to int later on.

There are few ways of checking it, `!textField.getText().isEmpty()` and `textField.getText() != null`

---

Personally, i would use [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library StringUtils and just check if the string `isBlank(textField.getText())`

Additionally you should validate the input, as well You can use the mentioned library and use `StringUtils.isNumeric()` in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `textField.getText().equals(null)` will never work this only throws a `NullPointerException` better use `textField.getText()==null`.

Because the user can enter anything in the TextField you need to validate the input or create a try-catch-block.

The best way would to create a help method to parse the numbers, for example:

```
public static int readInteger(String text, int defaultValue) {
    if(text == null)
        return defaultValue;
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(text);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

---

By the way don't compare Strings with `x == "Pepsi"` only when you want to check if the String is null.
Read: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/8097737)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that user can write what he want in that textfield so u should also take care when textfield have a value like 'asd';

```
  String QtyOfChickenBurgerAsString =textField.getText();
  Integer QtyOfChickenBurger=null;
  try{
  QtyOfChickenBurger = Integer.valueOf(QtyOfChickenBurgerAsString);
  }catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(" this is not a number ...do whatever u wanna do");
  }

  if (QtyOfChickenBurger!=null){
    System.out.println("integer value of field text  "+QtyOfChickenBurger);
  }
```

I suggest create variables with starting letter in lower case ,and when you compare using equals use the constant first.Also you could find a better solution by using components which accept only numbers in their text.

Answer (score 0):

As of java 9, the Object class has a convenience method for handling null values and it is found in  java.util.

```
public static String processEmployee(String fullName){
    // if fullName is null then second argument is returned,otherwise fullName is
    String name = Objects.requireNonNullElse(fullName,  "empty");
    // the processing goes here ...
    return name;
}
```